# How can I pin edges in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

I want to maintain the edges of a surface pinned while I'm sculpting it to keep its positions. Is this possible?

[image]
Edges that I want to pin

[image]

After sculpt, the edges change its locations

[image]

Thanks for the comment! But the problem after hiding the edges, is that it generates a flat face. I want that part also constructed with a grid

Comment: Does hiding them work? Select the edges you want "pinned" and press `H` to hide them, Blender generally keeps hidden geometry untouched

Comment: Alternative : using the mask brush. But in both cases you'll have what you called a 'flat face' in your edit. You'll need to smooth it manually or add additional edges loops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like lemon already suggested, the masking tools are your best choice. Yes, you will get the flat faces as well, just as with hiding them, but afterwards you can - with the mask still active - smooth the borders using the smooth brush.

on the bottom left of the screenshot you can see the Hide/Mask menu. Choose one that fits you best. My example is so simple I was able to use box select for this. Basically mask everything except the boundary.

[image: Hide and Mask Menu]

after that, you'll see that the inner part turned black (that means it is masked), and the outer part is grey (editable).

[image: Boundary is white]

We need the opposite, so we invert the mask with <kbd>Ctrl + I</kbd>

[image: mask inverted]

Now we can sculpt as we like, ignoring the fact that we get heavily distorted faces on the outside.

[image: face distorsion]

With the smooth brush, this can be fixed easily and with a lot of control!

[image: Smoothed result]